# Installing PHPUnit 3.8 via Pear

Tags: php, phpunit, pear

I can't upgrade PHPUnit from 3.7 to 3.8 with Pear. The following:

```
pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Returns

```
phpunit/PHPUnit is already installed and is the same as the released version 3.7.19
```

I've tried changing my pear preferred state to beta / devel which doesn't make a difference. Any ideas on how I can upgrade to 3.8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like 3.8 has been remove from the pear repo.

http://pear.phpunit.de/

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
$ pear clear-cache
```

to get rid of old cache files and try again.

If that does not help, explicitely use the version number:

```
$ pear upgrade -f phpunit/phpunit-3.8.0
```

Comment: If I use --force it still thinks I'm trying to upgrade to 3.7.19

Comment: do you have packages installed that depend on `phpunit <= 3.7.x`?

Comment: Not that I can find, I've also tried upgrading the dependencies for 3.8 which still didn't help.

Comment: which pear version is that? if not 1.9.4, upgrade first.

Comment: Yep it's 1.9.4 and PHP 5.4.14

Comment: Coincidentally, the reason I'm trying to upgrade is due to the define() + runInSeparateProcess = Constant already defined bug you flagged up on github recently !